# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown menu background not rendering in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap out of the box. I have a dropdown menu that works well on all the browsers except IE8. When click the button in ie8, the list items appear without the background but appears when I hover over the list items. If I do not choose an item from the dropdown menu and click on an area outside of the dropdown, the background moves but does not disappear. Any idea why? Here is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<div class="input-prepend">
    <button class="btn"><div id="searchThis">Name</div>&nbsp;</button>
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="name" rel="Last name, First name"><a href="#">Name</a></li>
        <li id="org-name" rel="Organization Name"><a href="#">Org Name</a></li>
        <li id="org-code" rel="Organization Code"><a href="#">Org Code</a></li>
        <li id="state" rel="State"><a href="#">State</a></li>
        <li id="country" rel="Country"><a href="#">Country</a></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="input-append">
         <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" name="search" class="input-text span12" />
         <button type="submit" title="" class="button btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-search icon-white"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue, exactly as you described. The dropdown background appeared in the correct place for a millisecond after clicking, then jumped out of position and does not disappear when clicking elsewhere on the page.

I tried commenting out the various IE8 only javascript files such as html5shiv.js and respond.js, but that didn't work.

The problem was that I was applying CSSPie to the class `.dropdown-menu`, so that the rounded corners were supported in IE8. This was obviously conflicting with bootstrap.js somehow, so after commenting out the line below in my CSS, the dropdown background appeared as expected (albeit with square corners!)

```
.dropdown-menu{behavior:url(/Resources/CSS/CSSPie/PIE.htc)}
```